# Need to control fan speed at extremely low level

Tags: motor-controller, fan

The application is to vent an electric BBQ smoker. I'll be moving to an apartment and have a serious pulled pork & pastrami addiction. I tried computer fans and 4" in-duct fan with different controllers. Controllers go from zero to about 40% then variable from 40% to 100%. The speed I'll need would be approx. the speed of smoke coming out of the smoker. To fast and wood chips would burn too quickly and temp control would be difficult. Too slow and smoke will back into the apartment. Ducting would go from the smoker thru the ductwork and fan and exit thru the existing kitchen vent. I'm open to any fan and any control device. Would even consider devising a temp control for the fan. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look into an Arduino.  You can use one with a gate driver and MOSFET to drive the fan with a PWM signal.  What do you want to use as a control variable (temp etc)?  What do commercial controllers use?

Comment: I do recommend doing what @PICyPICyPICy is proposing, but if you just want something quick and dirty then you can just get a potentiometer, short middle pin with one of the two outer pins and use as a rheostat and put in series with the fan. It's dirty, but it's also quick.

Comment: Could you leave the fan on full and use a [damper](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Heating-Venting-Cooling-HVAC-Parts-Accessories-Ducting-Venting-Duct-Accessories-Dampers/N-5yc1vZc5ho) in the duct?

Comment: Please read the discussion [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/85244/62506) before you attempt to operate any sort of smoker indoors. In general, it is a VERY BAD IDEA unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Hm, we've had many "kill yourself with high voltage" posts here, but this is the first "kill yourself with carbon monoxide" post I see. Please explain how an electric smoker works, I'm a bit at a loss...

Comment: Agree to Dave. Aside from smoke, a smoker creates high amounts of carbon monoxide, which is odorless and highly toxic. If your venting fails for any reason - blackout - you are likely killing yourself.

Comment: @Peufeu: an electric smoker technically isn't much more than a pot filled with a layer of beech wood chips on an electric stove. Some people think it's safe because "it's electric".

Comment: You are the worst kind of tenant >:(

Comment: @BryanBoettcher you have not met some of my tenants.

Comment: @Janka Okay, such device of dooom is best left operating outside. If OP has a balcony, then maybe...

Comment: 1) Most electrical motors aren't suitable to be used at low (0-60%) range of their maximum speed. 2) The position of the vent where the smoke will get out, will your neighbours of the floor above fell the smell? Maybe this will bring more troubles. 3) Consider buying pork and pastrami.

Comment: use a stepping motor to run the fan

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not really an electronics solution but it sounds like maybe you could just use a large hood with a constant ventilation rate over your smoker.

As long as the hood exhausted at a rate equal to or greater than the exhaust rate of your smoker smoke wouldn't back up into your apartment.  You wouldn't need to worry about burning chips too quickly because excess flow for the exhaust would come directly from the room.

Instead of a large hood you could maybe accomplish the same thing with a draft hood like the kind used on gas hot water heaters.

[image: draft hood]